# Функция отключающая кнопку если инпут с радио не выбран

Tags: javascript

Вопрос в том, как присвоить кнопке disabled пока не выбран один из радио инпутов. Функция которая сменяет блоки с радио инпутами

```
function next_qestion() {
if(document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display == "block"){
    document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('qestion3').style.display = "block";
}
if(document.getElementById('qestion1').style.display == "block"){
    document.getElementById('qestion1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display = "block";
}
```

Сами блоки

```
    <div id="qestion1" style="display:none;">
        <p>Задание 1.</p>
        <div id="container"><audio id="sound" src="rvpi/1.1.wav" preload="auto" controls></audio></div>
    <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
        <p><span id="v_34"></span><br><br><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="28" >Вот он, справа.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="250">На автобусе №12.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="43">Я не еду в центр.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="qestion2" style="display:none;">
        <p>Задание 2.</p>
        <div id="container"><audio id="sound" src="rvpi/2.1.wav" preload="auto" controls></audio></div>
    <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
        <p><span id="v_35"></span><br><br><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="28" >У меня на родине никогда не бывает снега.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="250">Вчера весь день шёл снег.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
            <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="43">Думаю, да.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
<button id="next" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:10%;width:200px;" onclick="next_qestion();">Вперед</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не настаиваю, но есть возможность сделать все только на CSS

```css
a:not(#start) {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  user-select: none;
}

input:checked ~ a:not(#start) {
  pointer-events: unset;
  opacity: 1;
}

*:target ~ #start,
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hidden:target {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1" class="hidden">
  Question 1<br>
  <input type=radio name='one'>
  <input type=radio name='one'>
  <input type=radio name='one'>
  <br>
  <a href="#q2"><button>next</button></a>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="hidden">
  Question 2<br>
  <input type=radio name='two'>
  <input type=radio name='two'>
  <input type=radio name='two'>
  <br>
  <a href="#q3"><button>next</button></a>
</div>

<div id="q3" class="hidden">
  Question 3<br>
  <input type=radio name='three'>
  <input type=radio name='three'>
  <input type=radio name='three'>
  <br>
  <a href="#done"><button>finish</button></a>
</div>

<div id="done" class="hidden">done</div>

<a id="start" href="#q1"><button>start quiz</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ли я понял, что вам требуется такой код:

```
// получить список всех элементов radio
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('#z_1');

// определить, выбран ли какой-нибудь элемент radio    
let isChecked = false;
    
for (let obj of radios) {
    if (obj.checked) {
        isChecked = true;
    }
}

// установить состояние кнопки
document.querySelector('#next').disabled = !isChecked;
```

P.S.

я бы возможно использовал бы не `id`, а `class` для radio-элементов, ну или хотя бы делал разные id для разных блоков - а то у вас для всех 6 элементов 1 и тот же id

Comment: Да, нужен подобный код, он работает но возникает проблема, мне нужно чтобы кнопка активировалась на определенном блоке если выбран радио, а на следующем отключалась и была отключена пока не будет выбран радио на втором блоке

Comment: @user407430, я бы обернул приведенный функционал в функцию, которую навесил бы на все радиокнопки: 1) всем нужным радиокнопкам добавил бы общий класс, к примеру `tasks-radio`, 2) повесил бы обработчик изменения `change` или нажатия `click` на элементы, имеющие этот класс 3) при срабатывании функции выполнял бы приведенный выше код 4) функция на вход (ну или через глобальные переменные) передавал бы `id` за которым следить 5) при переходе к следующему блоку задавал бы соответствующий id  ИЛИ 4) и 5) раз вы все равно скрываете радио заменил бы на очистку (сброс) `checked` у всех `tasks-radio`

Comment: Сейчас привязал к одному блоку эту функцию, но она почему-то срабатывает только после обновления страницы, то есть выбираю радио инпут, но кнопка активной не становится, обновляю страницу, выбранный инпут сохраняется и кнопка активируется. Не могу понять почему так

Comment: @user407430, работающий код на какой-нибудь ресурс где можно код редактировать закиньте - посмотрю в чем дело

Comment: https://codepen.io/Evan__Young/pen/pobbjRP?editors=1010

Comment: @user407430, так вы на событие `DOMContentLoaded` навесили - так контент у вас и загружается только 1 раз - вначале :) Вообще для такой задачи я бы сделал более универсальный код - у вас же каждый блок имеет отдельную функцию - зачем это? В идеале список вопросов и т.д. конечно лучше в отдельном массиве хранить и динамически генерировать на странице (а старое удалять), но даже без этого - можно все блоки вопросов делать через универсальный класс типа `task-1`, 'task-2' и т.д. и при перехода по кнопке просто вычислять как будет называться следующий класс - если у вас конечно не 2 блока/вопросов

Comment: Не могли бы привести наглядный пример, не могу понять вашу мысль